# Tyepscript cast object to parent object

Tags: typescript, casting

```
class base {
  a: number;
  b: number;
}

class child extends base {
  c: number;
}

let obj: child = { a: 4, b: 5, c: 6 };
let test: base = obj as base;
console.log(test);
```

Will output { a: 4, b: 5, c: 6 }

How to output { a: 4, b: 5 } ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Types do not change how your program works. They only exist in during "compilation".

To change the output you will have to make your code remove the property.

See

- [Anders Hejlsberg on Build 2013](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-314) (watch at 18:05): he mentions that types will just "evaporate", they are just a design-time artifact. They don't change your code, it is your code minus types.
- [Your code on TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20b%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20child%20extends%20base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20c%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20obj%3A%20child%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%204%2C%20b%3A%205%2C%20c%3A%206%20%7D%3B%0D%0Alet%20test%3A%20base%20%3D%20obj%20as%20base%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(test)%3B) you can see that types don't affect the output

So, to output only `a` and `b` you have to call a code to delete `c`

```
delete obj.c;
```

Comment: And I see as well that the property definition also disappear after compilation, so no way to use hasOwnProperty... I would like to find a generic way if the class properties change. With delete, I will have to change the code to different place. It would be great to be able to change only the structure of the class. :-/